# how to fix the error in 'git submodule update'

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a super project named Root and a submodule named subB on which I have no write permission. now I want to git a new branch in another machine .  but when run "git submodule update", get error :

"fatal: reference is not a tree: b4ec396a0e1da795a5187f7acf90f686c23c6940
Unable to checkout 'b4ec396a0e1da795a5187f7acf90f686c23c6940' in submodule path 'subB'".  so I tried all kinds of ways to resolve the issue but I failed. who can answer the following questions for me , thanks:

1. does the ref 'b4ec396a0e1da795a5187f7acf90f686c23c6940' means local commit in submodule subB? I could see its info only by 'git log b4ec396a0e1da795a5187f7acf90f686c23c6940'  in submodule directory 'subB', but in super project I see nothing by the same command.
2. the ref means a commit in local sumodule repo? because i have no write permission for the remote repo. so I am sure it only on local. buy why the error occurs when I update in another machine. the remote repo should have no idea about the local commit!
3. how to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

It probably means that a commit b4ec396 was done in `subB`, but not pushed in `origin/subB` (the upstream repo for `subB`).
However, the parent repo has recorded that **[gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309)** ([special entry in the index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19354410/6309)), and was pushed to `origin/Root`.

On the other machine, when the parent repo `Root` is cloned, it cannot checkout `subB`, because it references a SHA1 which is not present in `origin/subB`.

Comment: how to get to know what is the gitlink and revert the commit in parent repo?

Comment: @yong the gitlink is `b4ec396`, but since it does not exit, all you can do is `git clone` the `subB` repo in the `subB` folder, then, from `Root` folder, check `git status`: it should say the gitlink has changed (since the `subB` repo would be checked out at a different SHA1) .You can then add and commit that `subB` gitlink from the `Root` folder, and `git push` it. That way, the next `git clone Root` followed by a `git submodule update init` will actually work, since it will ask for an *existing* SHA1 of the `subB` repo.